# How to Hide empty div file if no url in the iframe?

Tags: php, html, iframe

Quick Question, How to hide this code in php: if there is nothing to show or no link in "src" or unknown?

The problem is, Hence the `<div class="resp-container">` in .css have `padding-top: 56.25%;`. All of the box have padding even the iframe is empty.

I hope my explanation is clear to you guys and I'm sorry if its a bit hard to explain.

To understand what I mean here is my current webpage that have a problem: https://donpramis.com/timeline/

```
<div class="resp-container">
<iframe class="resp-iframe" src=(unknown) frameborder="0" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
</div>
```

Here is the complete code:

```
<div class="container">
   <h3 align="center"><a href="">Timeline (Beta)</a></a></h3><br />
   <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">My Journey</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body timeline-body">
                 <div class="timeline">
                  <div class="timeline__wrap">
                   <div class="timeline__items">
                   <?php 
                   foreach($result as $row)
                   {
                   ?>
                    <div class="timeline__item">
                     <div class="timeline__content">
                      <h2><?php echo $row["year"]; ?></h2>                   
                      <p><?php echo $row["comment"];?></p>
                      <p><a href="<?php echo $row["website"];?>"><?php echo $row["Site_Description"];?></a></p> 

<div id="resp-container">
<iframe class="resp-iframe" src="<?php echo $row["iframe_video"];?>" frameborder="0" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
</div>
<img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $row["timelime_image"];?>" alt="" />

                     </div>
                    </div>                                         
                   <?php
                   }
                   ?>
                   </div>
                  </div>
                 </div>
                </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: if you want to hide this code in php then please show your php code first

Comment: @M.Hemant here is the complete code... I just remove the html,head,header, and footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the Div with iframe after checking the value for src. For example:

```
<?php if($row['iframe_video']!='' && $row['iframe_video']!='unknown') echo '<div id="resp-container">
<iframe class="resp-iframe" src="'. $row["iframe_video"].'" frameborder="0" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
</div>'; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to check for the content inside the Iframe. If content does not exist, use hide() to hide the resp-container;

```
if(!$("#iframeid").contents().find("body").length) {

   $('.resp-container').hide();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to validate the data.
for validating you can use empty check `if(empty($row["iframe_video"])` function.
here the code.

```
<div id="resp-container">
    <?php if (empty($row["iframe_video"]) || $row["iframe_video"] != 'unknown'): ?>
        <iframe class="resp-iframe" src="<?php echo $row["iframe_video"];?>" frameborder="0" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
    <?php endif ?>
</div>
```